# Java Collection with multiple keys that refer to a different value that is also sortable (by key and index)

Tags: java, collections, knapsack-problem

I had a lot of problems with my program recently, as I am not able to create a Collection which has duplicate keys at the same that refer to a different value. It's like an array in a List.
I already tried a TreeMap, as so I tried a SortedTreeMap, which seem to work with the idea of identical keys, but the problem here is that you can only sort a (Sorted)TreeMap by key, and not by value.

For Example, I have a game:
Player one scored 100 points, then he scores 200, and then he only scores 150
Player two scores, 140, 120, and 210.

Is it possible to write this into a Collection, which also sorts it that the output would be like this:

`1 = [200, 150, 100], 2 = [210, 140, 120] //Note that the values are sorted`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot achieve this with a single class that fits into the Java Collections framework, you can build a wrapper that uses multiple classes from that framework or just use them in your other code.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the example data you gave, I'm speculating that the collection of scores for any player might contain duplicates. That makes this a little harder, because you can't use a standard `java.util.SortedSet` implemenation (`Set`s don't allow duplicate values). You also can't have the scores be `List`s because the contract of the `List` interface states that `add()`-ing always inserts at the *end* of the list, which is contrary to maintaining a *sorted* collection.

So even though there isn't a perfect collection class included in the Java standard library, there are a couple of options I can think of.

**Option A**: Store the scores as an ordinary Collection (perhaps a `List`), and re-sort them either on every add or on-demand when retrieving the scores for a particular player. Here is an example:

```java
public class ExplicitlySortingScorekeeper {

    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> scores = new HashMap<>();

    public void addScore(Integer player, Integer score) {
        List<Integer> playerScores = scores.get(player);
        if (playerScores == null) {
            playerScores = new ArrayList<>();
            scores.put(score, playerScores);
        }

        playerScores.add(score);
        playerScores.sort(null);
    }

    public List<Integer> getScores(Integer player) {
        List<Integer> playerScores = scores.get(player);
        if (playerScores != null) {
            playerScores.sort(null);
        }

        return playerScores;
    }
}
```

Note that this code shows the sorting both during add and during get; it's not necessary to do it both, you could choose which place you want to call `List.sort()`.

**Option B**: If you're willing to use a third-party library (specifically, Apache Commons Collections 4), it has an interface, `SortedBag` that fits the need. Here's an example that uses a `TreeBag`, an implementation of `SortedBag`, to keep the collection of scores sorted at all times.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.SortedBag;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.bag.TreeBag;

public class AutoSortedScorekeeper {

    private Map<Integer, TreeBag<Integer>> scores = new HashMap<>();

    public void addScore(Integer player, Integer score) {
        TreeBag<Integer> playerScores = scores.get(player);
        if (playerScores == null) {
            playerScores = new TreeBag<>();
            scores.put(score, playerScores);
        }

        playerScores.add(score);
    }

    public SortedBag<Integer> getScores(Integer player) {
        return scores.get(player);
    }
}
```

---

I notice that your example data output shows the scores sorted in *descending* order, which is opposite of the natural ordering of `Integer`. So you'll probably have to use a custom `Comparator` in either the `sort()` call or the `TreeBag` constructor. `Comparator.reverseOrder()` will work if you stick with the natural ordering of score (ie, Integer).

Comment: Thank you! I‘ll try that when I get home